# how to update attribute value of english store in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to update brand attribute value of english store but when i try to update from magento admin english stores, it's not updating. can anyone please let me know how to update this attribute? Thanks

Comment: Did your check if your atribute is corrected assigned at Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute Sets on a group?

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_CopyStoreViewValues